# Filling missing dates in a grouped time series - a tidyverse-way?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse

Given a data.frame that contains a time series and one or ore grouping fields. So we have several time series - one for each grouping combination.
But some dates are missing.
So, what's the easiest (in terms of the most "tidyverse way") of adding these dates with the right grouping values?

Normally I would say I generate a data.frame with all dates and do a full_join with my time series. But now we have to do it for each combination of grouping values -- and fill in the grouping values.

Let's look at an example:

First I create a data.frame with missing values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1234)
# Time series should run vom 2017-01-01 til 2017-01-10
date <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from=ymd("2017-01-01"), to=ymd("2017-01-10"), by="days"), v = 1)
# Two grouping dimensions
d1   <- data.frame(d1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), v = 1)
d2   <- data.frame(d2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), v = 1)

# Generate the data.frame
df <- full_join(date, full_join(d1, d2)) %>%
  select(date, d1, d2) 
# and ad to value columns
df$v1 <- runif(200)
df$v2 <- runif(200)

# group by the dimension columns
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(d1, d2)

# create missing dates
df.missing <- df %>%
  filter(v1 <= 0.8)

# So now  2017-01-01 and 2017-01-10, A, 5 are missing now
df.missing %>%
  filter(d1 == "A" & d2 == 5)

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   d1, d2 [1]
        date     d1    d2         v1        v2
      <date> <fctr> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2017-01-02      A     5 0.21879954 0.1335497
2 2017-01-03      A     5 0.32977018 0.9802127
3 2017-01-04      A     5 0.23902573 0.1206089
4 2017-01-05      A     5 0.19617465 0.7378315
5 2017-01-06      A     5 0.13373890 0.9493668
6 2017-01-07      A     5 0.48613541 0.3392834
7 2017-01-08      A     5 0.35698708 0.3696965
8 2017-01-09      A     5 0.08498474 0.8354756
```

So to add the missing dates I generate a data.frame with all dates:

```
start <- min(df.missing$date)
end   <- max(df.missing$date)

all.dates <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(start, end, by="day"))
```

No I want to do something like (remember: df.missing is group_by(d1, d2))

```
df.missing %>%
  do(my_join())
```

So let's define my_join():

```
my_join <- function(data) {
  # get value of both dimensions
  d1.set <- data$d1[[1]]
  d2.set <- data$d2[[1]]

  tmp <- full_join(data, all.dates) %>%
    # First we need to ungroup.  Otherwise we can't change d1 and d2 because they are grouping variables
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(
      d1 = d1.set,
      d2 = d2.set 
    ) %>%
    group_by(d1, d2)

  return(tmp)
}
```

Now we can call my_join() for each combination and have a look at "A/5"

```
df.missing %>%
  do(my_join(.)) %>%
  filter(d1 == "A" & d2 == 5)

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   d1, d2 [1]
         date     d1    d2         v1        v2
       <date> <fctr> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2017-01-02      A     5 0.21879954 0.1335497
 2 2017-01-03      A     5 0.32977018 0.9802127
 3 2017-01-04      A     5 0.23902573 0.1206089
 4 2017-01-05      A     5 0.19617465 0.7378315
 5 2017-01-06      A     5 0.13373890 0.9493668
 6 2017-01-07      A     5 0.48613541 0.3392834
 7 2017-01-08      A     5 0.35698708 0.3696965
 8 2017-01-09      A     5 0.08498474 0.8354756
 9 2017-01-01      A     5         NA        NA
10 2017-01-10      A     5         NA        NA
```

Great! That's what we were looking for.
But we need to define d1 and d2 in my_join and it feels a little bit clumsy.

So, is there any tidyverse-way of this solution?

P.S.: I've put the code into a gist: https://gist.github.com/JerryWho/1bf919ef73792569eb38f6462c6d7a8e

Comment: JerryWho you've received some good answers below. If any helped you, consider accepting it as an answer (check mark to the left). It lets the community know the answer worked for your case. You can change your accepted answer in the future if you wish.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`tidyr`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) has some great tools for these sorts of problems. Take a look at [`complete`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

want <- df.missing %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(nesting(d1, d2), date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = "day"))

want %>% filter(d1 == "A" & d2 == 5) 

#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>        d1    d2       date         v1        v2
#>    <fctr> <dbl>     <date>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1      A     5 2017-01-01         NA        NA
#>  2      A     5 2017-01-02 0.21879954 0.1335497
#>  3      A     5 2017-01-03 0.32977018 0.9802127
#>  4      A     5 2017-01-04 0.23902573 0.1206089
#>  5      A     5 2017-01-05 0.19617465 0.7378315
#>  6      A     5 2017-01-06 0.13373890 0.9493668
#>  7      A     5 2017-01-07 0.48613541 0.3392834
#>  8      A     5 2017-01-08 0.35698708 0.3696965
#>  9      A     5 2017-01-09 0.08498474 0.8354756
#> 10      A     5 2017-01-10         NA        NA
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Some rows are added. But esp. A/5 is still missing 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-10. I think that's because min(date) and max(date) are per group. Maybe you have to ungroup before complete and group_by afterwards.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's because I first ungrouped `df.missing`.

Comment: `complete` is perfect here, wish I'd thought of it

Answer (score 3):

package `tsibble` function `fill_gaps` should do the job easily.

```r
library(tsibble)
df.missing %>% 
  # tsibble format
  as_tsibble(key = c(d1, d2), index = date) %>% 
  # fill gaps
  fill_gaps(.full = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse way starting with `df.missing`

```
library(tidyverse)
ans <- df.missing %>% 
          nest(date) %>% 
          mutate(data = map(data, ~seq.Date(start, end, by="day"))) %>% 
          unnest(data) %>%
          rename(date = data) %>%
          left_join(., df.missing, by=c("date","d1","d2"))

ans %>% filter(d1 == "A" & d2 == 5)
```

Output

```
      d1    d2       date         v1        v2
   <fctr> <dbl>     <date>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1      A     5 2017-01-01         NA        NA
 2      A     5 2017-01-02 0.21879954 0.1335497
 3      A     5 2017-01-03 0.32977018 0.9802127
 4      A     5 2017-01-04 0.23902573 0.1206089
 5      A     5 2017-01-05 0.19617465 0.7378315
 6      A     5 2017-01-06 0.13373890 0.9493668
 7      A     5 2017-01-07 0.48613541 0.3392834
 8      A     5 2017-01-08 0.35698708 0.3696965
 9      A     5 2017-01-09 0.08498474 0.8354756
10      A     5 2017-01-10         NA        NA
```

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
Here's an alternative approach that uses `expand.grid` and `dplyr` verbs

```
with(df.missing, expand.grid(unique(date), unique(d1), unique(d2))) %>%
  setNames(c("date", "d1", "d2")) %>%
  left_join(., df.missing, by=c("date","d1","d2"))
```

output (head)

```
          date d1 d2          v1          v2
1   2017-01-01  A  1 0.113703411 0.660754634
2   2017-01-02  A  1 0.316612455 0.422330675
3   2017-01-03  A  1 0.553333591 0.424109178
4   2017-01-04  A  1          NA          NA
5   2017-01-05  A  1          NA          NA
6   2017-01-06  A  1 0.035456727 0.352998502
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `read.zoo` creates a wide form zoo object and to that we merge the dates.  Then we convert that back to a long data frame using `fortify.zoo` and spread out out `v1` and `v2` using `spread`.

Note that:

- if we can assume that each date appears in at least one combination of the split variables, i.e. `sort(unique(df.missing$date))` contains all the dates, then we could omit the `merge` line and no joins would have to be done at all.  The test data `df.missing` shown in the question does have this property:

  ```
  all(all.dates$date %in% df.missing$date)
  ## [1] TRUE
  ```
- we could stop after the `merge` (or after `read.zoo` if each date is present at least once as in prior point) if a wide form zoo object can be used as that already has all the dates.

In the code below the line marked ### can be omitted with the development version of zoo (1.8.1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

split.vars <- c("d1", "d2")
df.missing %>%
   as.data.frame %>%     ###
   read.zoo(split = split.vars) %>%
   merge(zoo(, seq(start(.), end(.), "day"))) %>%
   fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE) %>%
   separate(Series, c("v", split.vars)) %>%
   spread(v, Value)
```

**Update:** Note simplification in zoo 1.8.1 .