# Add rows for missing timestamp data in df

Tags: r, data-manipulation, rowwise

I have a *df* like this:

| Line | Sensor | Day | Time | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 10:00:00 | 56 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 11:00:00 | 42 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 12:00:00 | 87 |
| 4 | A | 1 | 12:20:00 | 12 |
| 5 | A | 1 | 12:50:00 | 44 |

I would like to create some rows. Considering that measurements should be taken every 10 minutes I would like to add a non-constant number of rows (i.e there should be 6 between line 1 and 2; two rows between line 3 and 4; 3 rows between line 4 and five)
in order to get something similar to this:

| Line | Sensor | Day | Time | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 10:00:00 | 56 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 10:10:00 | 54 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 10:20:00 | 35 |
| 4 | A | 1 | 10:30:00 | 11 |
| 5 | A | 1 | 10:40:00 | 45 |
| 6 | A | 1 | 10:50:00 | 56 |
| 7 | A | 1 | 11:00:00 | 90 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 13 | A | 1 | 12:00:00 | 87 |
| 14 | A | 1 | 12:10:00 | 97 |
| 15 | A | 1 | 12:20:00 | 42 |
| 16 | A | 1 | 12:30:00 | 67 |
| 4 | A | 1 | 12:40:00 | 76 |
| 5 | A | 1 | 12:50:00 | 11 |

Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the tidyr function `complete()`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56192036/12957340 ?

Comment: You're going to have to explain the logic. How are the missing values for `Measurement` derived? Why does the value for Sensor A Day 1 11:00:00 = 42 in the first data frame, but = 90 in the second?

Comment: @neilfws in the example the `Measurement` values were random. I was thinking to measure the distance between the original rows(i.e suppose at time 10:00:00 `Measurement` = 80 and at `Time` 10:30:00 `Measurement` = 50), take the difference in `Measurement` at the two timestamps, divide it by the number of rows to be added so I'll have something like `time`: 10:10:00 `Measurement` = 70; `Time` 10:20:00 `Measurement` = 60 ecc.