# R: complete cells below by adding 1 each time

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column about time and this column contains some `NA`. I would like to fill these cells with the year before + 1 (if the missing cell is not the beginning of the serie). Here's a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(2000, NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002))
```

I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130246/filling-missing-dates-in-a-grouped-time-series-a-tidyverse-way)

```
df <- df %>%
  complete(y = seq(min(y), max(y), by = "year"))
```

but I can't find out how to do so. Any idea?

**Edit:** expected output:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002))
```

**Note:** I would prefer a `dplyr` solution.

**Note 2 (October 23rd 2019):** The three answers so far are good but quite complicated. I'm really surprised that it is not possible to do that simply (for example, having the possibility to add a lag in the `fill` function would be really useful I think).

Comment: Hi, Could you post the desired output too?

Comment: sure, I added it

Comment: it's not clear what you want to happen when say the first value of y is an `NA`? Or are you saying that cannot happen?

Comment: Will you have one such gap or many scuh gaps?

Comment: when they are NA some where, there are on the full serie. Here, I put 2000 to have a point from where I could fill the other NA but originally, the dataframe was of the form: ```df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(NA, NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002))```

Comment: so if you have a solution to fill for all the NA, I will take it but I thought it would be easier to find a solution if I manually changed the starting point of the serie and to fill the other ```NA``` from this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a bit annoying but completely vectorized in `dplyr`. I doubled your `df` into a new `df2` to try across a couple gapped occurrences.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(2000, NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002))

df2 <- bind_rows(df, df)
```

Basically you need to create groups across the blocks with `NA`. Then you can calculate a within-group `cumsum` and use `fill` to drag down the prior value. It is annoying because of all the lines.

```
df2 %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(y) & lag(is.na(y), default = FALSE))) %>%
  mutate(add_year = cumsum(is.na(y))) %>%
  fill(y) %>%
  mutate(y = y + add_year) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp, -add_year)
```

Comment: there must be an error in your Edit code, the output for ```df2$y``` is: ```[1] 2000 2001 2002 2000 2000 2000 2000 2001 2002 2002 2002 2002```

Comment: Ah yeah I think there might be. I tagged that on fast. I'll just clear the edit code.

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use `ave` in combination with `cumsum` to split your dataset and apply there `seq`, as you have tried already.

```
df$y <- ave(df$y, cumsum(!is.na(df$y)), FUN=function(x)
    seq(x[1], length.out = length(x)))
identical(df, dfExpected)
#[1] TRUE
df$y
#[1] 2000 2001 2002 2000 2001 2002
```

In case it starts with `NA` and you want then to let it start with `2000` you can use `replace`:

```
df2$y <-ave(df2$y, cumsum(!is.na(df2$y)), FUN=function(x) 
   seq(replace(x[1],is.na(x[1]),2000), length.out = length(x)))
identical(df2, dfExpected)
#[1] TRUE
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(2000, NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002))
dfExpected <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                 y = c(NA, NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002))
```

Comment: that works, but I would prefer a ```dplyr``` solution (I would validate your answer later if there are no more answers proposed)

Answer (score 0):

This uses `dplyr` functions `case_when()` and `lag` combined with a while-loop in a custom-function.

Output is as expected, try it out.

```r
library(dplyr)
lag_years <- function(df){
  while (anyNA(df$y))
    {
    df %>%
      mutate(y = case_when(is.na(y)&!is.na(lag(y))~lag(y)+1,TRUE~y)) %>%
      {.} -> df
  }
  return(df)
}

lag_years(df) %>%
head()
```

Comment: your code works, but when I apply it to a dataframe of several thousands of lines, it takes way too long (from my point of view)

Comment: @bretauv I feared as much, the while-loop really is brute-force. There might be a way to optimize the solution but I fear GKi's way might be better for now.